# How can we create batches of Arraylist in Java 8?

Tags: java, hibernate, java-8, batch-insert

I get Arraylist of object of say 1000 elements and i want to create batch of 100.

How to do it in java 8 in some elegant way?

I have following entity to iterate upon which has size of 1000:

```
List<CustomerAgreement> customerAgreement
```

Now i will call following methods after above

```
    customerAgreementDao.createAll(customerAgreement);
        customerAgreementDao.flush();
```

How can i create batches from above entity and call above two methods in that batch?

Current Standard way of doing this is somewhat like:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
for  ( int i=0; i<888888; i++ ) {
    TableA record = new TableA();
    record.setXXXX();
    session.save(record)
    if ( i % 50 == 0 ) { 
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
    }
}
tx.commit();
session.close();
```

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: Updated tags for database too but here i am just looking Java 8 way to create batches. I am taking it is general scenario where database is one of it. Thanks

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: Ok you mean i should int batchForInsertsSize; initialValue = 0; int totalSize = customerAgreement.size(); and just create loop using totalsize/batchForInsertsSize and in that loop just change initialvalue and batchforinsertssize+initial value??? Isn't it standard way to do so?

Comment: since you are doing terminal operation and also you are not returning anything, in that case you can design [Consumer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) to your needs

Comment: @emotionlessbananas: Could you please give me some example.

Comment: I can try making one. Till then check for [Stream#forEach()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html), which is similar you are looking for

Comment: @fatherazrael That would be a way to go about it yes. No doubt there are others, maybe even including lambda's as emotionlessbananas will be trying to show you.

Comment: I agree with @MaartenBodewes. Only thing I have got so for is some fancy,buggy implementation for your code reference and here it is: 
  `public void consumerTest() {
    AtomicInteger ai = new AtomicInteger(0);
    IntStream.range(0, 100).boxed().map(Table::new)
        .forEach(r -> this.forEachConsumer(r, ai.addAndGet(1)));
  }

  public void forEachConsumer(Table table, Integer counter) {
    System.out.println(counter);
    if (counter % 30 == 0) {
      System.err.println(counter);
    }
  }` and I **will not recommend this code inside production**

Comment: I see that you've asked quite a lot of questions the last few days. Don't forget to follow up on them! Accept answers or indicate why they are not sufficient.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: Sure. Actually i am working on several modules in parallel and for many of them i am beginner. :(  (Java CDI, Boot, Mongo, now throwing me into docker and quarkus thing) . I will surely accept answer once i implement the logic and it works fine. Regarding this question, i am stuck with CDI part so not able to tested (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59104245/why-cdi-is-not-working-inject-inside-singleton-and-named?noredirect=1#comment104440953_59104245). So most questions are related to one another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd myself use `List.subList`, as I'm not so into lambda's; they generally make your code less readable in my opinion.

This should work - if you don't mind I've scaled back on the array:

```
// create list as demo
var list = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
    list.add(Integer.toString(i));
}

int batchSize = 3;

// the code
int offset = 0;
while (offset < list.size()) {
    // make sure the end offset doesn't go past the end
    int endOffset = Math.min(offset + batchSize, list.size());

    // call or add it to anything else, or even use streaming afterwards
    System.out.println(list.subList(offset, endOffset));
    offset = endOffset;
}
```

results in

```
[0, 1, 2]
[3, 4, 5]
[6, 7, 8]
[9, 10, 11]
[12]
```

Beware that the sublists are *not* copies, any changes to the objects in the list will be reflected in the sub lists, while structural changes (resizing) to the original list will result, well, probably in a mess. This also goes for the other way around, although structural changes to the `subList` are possible.

Comment: Well, changes to any objects that aren't immutable such as Java `String`, obviously. No way of changing those without black art.

Answer (score 2):

```
    int itemsPerBatch = 100;
    int totalBatches = (customerAgreements.size()+itemsPerBatch-1)/itemsPerBatch;
    int offset = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<totalBatches; i++) {
        List<String> currentBatch = customerAgreements.subList(offset, Math.min(offset+itemsPerBatch, customerAgreements.size()));
        offset+=itemsPerBatch;
    }
```